# How can I sum two complex matrix in C++?

Tags: c++, oop, matrix, sum, addition

I have a class for complex numbers whose data members are im (the imaginary part) and re (the real part). Now I want to sum 2 matrix that come from the class Matrix (A and B) and put the sum in another matrix (C). This is what I tried. Any advice?

The error I get is

```
no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'Matrix' and 'int')
```

```
inline Matrix& operator+(Matrix& A, Matrix& B)
{

 
        Matrix *C = new Matrix;
        C->rows = A.rows;
        C->columns = A.columns;
        for(int i = 0; i <  A.rows; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j <  A.columns; j++)
                C[i][j] = A[i][j] + B[i][j];
    }
    return **C;
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `new` to create the matrix? Use `Matrix C;`, and change the return type to just `Matrix`. Also the parameter types should be changed to `const Matrix &`. Hard to say more without seeing the exact error message and a [mcve].

Comment: Answering to the edit: the error means that you didn't provide overloaded `operator[]` for the matrix class, so the compiler doesn't know what `A[i][j]` (and others) means.

Answer (score 1):

Add a operator '+' inside class like:

```
Matrix  Matrix::operator+(const Matrix &other){
    Matrix result = Matrix<T>(rows, other.columns);
    if (this->rows == other.columns && this->columns == other.rows) {
        for (int i = 0; i < this->rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < this->columns; j++) {
                result.n[i][j] = other.n[i][j] + this->n[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
        return result;
    }
```

And the operator '=' to copy the result

```
Matrix&  Matrix::operator=(const Matrix &other ){
        if(this->columns<=other.columns && this->rows<=other.rows){
            for(int i=0;i<this->rows;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<this->columns;j++){
                    this->n[i][j]=other.n[i][j];
                    }
                }
            return (*this);
        }else{
            printf("ERROR");
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answers, but I don't understand what's the "n[i][j]" and where it comes from, can you help me?

Comment: @AleAlly n its a 2d array parameter inside class

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic Matrix implementation you could use.
Compatible with `std::complex` or whatever you own type is, as long as it's copy-constructible (see the main() in the link below).

```
template<class T>
struct Matrix {
    std::vector<T> data;
    size_t rows, cols;

    Matrix(size_t rows_, size_t cols_, T value=T()) 
    : data(rows_*cols_, value)
    , rows(rows_)
    , cols(cols_)
    {
    }

    Matrix() = default;

    Matrix(const Matrix& other) = default;
    Matrix& operator=(const Matrix& other) = default;

    Matrix(Matrix&& other) = default;
    Matrix& operator=(Matrix&& other) = default;
    
    T& operator()(size_t row, size_t col) {
        return data.at(flatIndex(row, col));
    }
    
    const T& operator()(size_t row, size_t col) const {
        return data.at(flatIndex(row, col));
    }

    Matrix operator+(const Matrix& other) const {
        assert(data.size() == other.data.size());
        assert(rows == other.rows);
        assert(cols == other.cols);

        Matrix sum = *this;
        for (size_t i=0; i<data.size(); i++) {
            sum.data.at(i) += other.data.at(i);
        }

        return sum;
    }

protected:
    size_t flatIndex(size_t row, size_t col) const {
        return row * cols + col;
    }
};

template<class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Matrix<T>& m) {
    for (size_t r = 0; r<m.rows; r++) {
        for (size_t c = 0; c<m.cols; c++) {
            os << m(r, c) << " ";
        }
        os << '\n';
    }
    return os;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Gvx5ac

If you really need performant/safe matrices, consider using a LinAlg library instead, like Eigen.